# Баланс скобок, нужно определить номер строки с лишней скобкой

Tags: c++, алгоритм, стек, олимпиада

> В текстовом файле, содержащем текст программы на языке Си,
>   проверить соответствие открывающихся и закрывающихся фигурных скобок {
>   и }.
>
> Во входном потоке в в виде набора строк задан текст, состоящий из
>   букв, цифр и специальных символов, таких как точка, тире, точка с
>   запятой, скобки и др. Размер файла не превышает 1МБ, а длина строки -
>   1000 символов.
>        Пример:
>
> ```
> int main() {
>  while (true) {
>   if (true) {
>   }
>   else { printf("Hello!");
>        }
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> В выходной поток вывести YES и через пробел максимальную глубину
>   вложения скобок или NO и через пробел номер первой строки, содержащей
>   скобку, которой не хватило пары.
>        Пример:
>
> ```
> YES 3
> ```

Есть идеи как определить номер первой строки со скобкой, которой не хватило пары? Нужен кратчайший путь, пусть примитивный, по возможности без стеков, в рамках существующего решения. Как задать переменной error нужное значение line?

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char sim,last='0';
  int q=0,max=0,error=0,line=1;
  ifstream text("input.txt");
  while ((sim=text.get())!=EOF)
  {
    if ((int)sim==10)
    {
      line++;
    }
    if (sim=='{')
    {
      q++;
      if (q>=max) max=q;
      last='{';
    }
    else if (sim=='}')
    {
      if (q)
      {
        q--;
        if (last!='{' && last!='}')
        {
          break;
        }
        last='}';
      }
    }
  }
  if (!q) cout << "YES " << max;
  else cout << "NO " << error;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Хранить стек номеров строк. Как только находится скобка `{` - кроме `++q` в стек вносить номер строки.

Как находится `}` - кроме `--q` снимать с вершины стека номер.

По окончании в стеке - номер скобки без пары. Или, при попытке снять что-то из пустого стека - без пары текущая `}`...

Можно ограничиться только стеком, без переменной `q`.

Что-то вроде

```
void getLineNo(istream& in)
{
    stack<int> st;
    int lineno = 0, maxsize = 0;
    string s;
    while(getline(in,s))
    {
        ++lineno;
        for(auto c: s)
        {
            if (c == '{')
            {
                st.push(lineno);
                if (maxsize < st.size())
                    maxsize = st.size();
            }
            else if (c == '}')
            {
                if (st.empty())
                {
                    cout << "NO " << lineno << endl;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!st.empty())
        cout << "NO " << st.top() << endl;
    else
        cout << "YES " << maxsize << endl;
}
```

Comment: vector'ом возможно реализовать?

Comment: там ещё нужна максимальная глубина вложенности. Это максимальная высота стека / 2?

Comment: а фигурные скобки в комментариях и текстовых строках могут быть?

Comment: Нет, это просто максимальная высота стека. И да, можно реализовать вектором.

Comment: @PavelGridin проверил на тестах, скобки в комментариях должны считаться, в строках (внутри кавычек) - нет

Comment: Тогда добавьте обработку строк... не забывая, что `\"` - это кавычки внутри строки. Будет забавно, если потребуется еще и анализировать корректность введенной программы :)

Comment: без лексического анализа тут наверное не обойтись

Comment: Действительно, как определить именно в какой строке лишняя  n - ная скобка, без лексического анализа?